# Problems with Copy of max range. User selected range

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I am trying to write a macro that will ask user to provide workbook, macro opens workbook. Than user selects the range for copy and specifies the worksheet to which paste data in Userform. Macro copy selected Range to the specified worksheet.

But I face some problems with it.

Here is code:

```
Public Sub copy_WB()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim wbk As Workbook, answer As String,lrow as long, lcol as long
Dim UserRange As Range

Prompt = "Select a cell for the output."
Title = "Select a cell"

answer = MsgBox("Would you like to clear all data?", vbYesNo, "Confirmation")
If answer = vbYes Then
    Call clear_all
End If

Set wbk = Get_workbook
If wbk Is Nothing Then
Exit Sub
End If
'   Display the Input Box
    On Error Resume Next
    Set UserRange = Application.InputBox( _
        Prompt:=Prompt, _
        Title:=Title, _
        Type:=8) 'Range selection

'   Was the Input Box canceled?
    If UserRange Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Canceled."
        Exit Sub
    Else
        UserRange.Parent.Parent.Activate
        UserRange.Parent.Activate
        lrow = UserRange(UserRange.Count).Row
        lcol = UserRange(UserRange.Count).Columns

        If lrow > 1000000 Or lcol > 15000 Then
        ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy
        Else
        UserRange.Copy
        End If

        sh_sel.Show
        Do While IsUserFormLoaded("sh_sel")
            DoEvents
        Loop

        ActiveSheet.Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(3).Range("A1") = lrow
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(3).Range("A2") = lcol
wbk.Close False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub


Private Sub clear_all()
Dim wb As Workbook, shs As Worksheet, lrow As Single, lcol As Single
Set wb = ThisWorkbook

For Each shs In wb.Worksheets

    With shs.UsedRange
        lrow = .Rows(.Rows.Count).Row
        lcol = .Columns(.Columns.Count).Column
    End With
        If Not (lrow = 0 Or lrow = 1) Then
    With shs
        .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(lrow, lcol)).clear
    End With
        End If
Next shs

End Sub

Function Get_workbook() As Workbook
    Dim wbk As Workbook, pathb As String
    pathb = ThisWorkbook.path
    ChDir pathb


    wbk_name = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Please choose File:", FileFilter:="Excel Files *.xls*(*.xls*),")
        On Error Resume Next
        If Len(Dir(wbk_name)) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "The file was not chosen - macro off."
        Exit Function
        Else
        Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(wbk_name)
        End If
        Set Get_workbook = wbk

End Function

Function IsUserFormLoaded(ByVal UFName As String) As Boolean
    Dim UForm As Object

    IsUserFormLoaded = False
    For Each UForm In VBA.UserForms
        If UForm.Name = UFName Then
            IsUserFormLoaded = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Function 'IsUserFormLoaded
```

The first problem that I am facing is when user press
[image]
The button which locates in the upper left corner of the sheet to select the entire sheet range, it will not be copied. I was trying to correct it somehow by adding the condition of last row of selected range is bigger then...(see code please).

But it does not actually works. sometimes it copy range, sometimes no.

The second problem: inputbox is disappears when macro run. Have no idea why it happans.

Userform code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim sh As Worksheet

    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        ListBox1.AddItem sh.Name
    Next sh

Me.StartUpPosition = 0
  Me.Left = Application.Left + (0.5 * Application.Width) - (0.5 * Me.Width)
  Me.Top = Application.Top + (0.5 * Application.Height) - (0.5 * Me.Height)
    HideTitleBar.HideTitleBar Me
End Sub


Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ListBox1.Value).Activate
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

User forms contains list of sheets in current workbook, after user selection of the sheet data would be pasted.

Comment: Is this a typo? `.Cells(2.1)` Don't see how the code can work at all if not.

Comment: What do you mean "typo"? And yes it works :)

Comment: @SJR - `Cells(2.1)` is translated to `Cells(2)` and this is exactly what the OP wants. That's a bit strange, it both works and does not work in the same time. :)

Comment: oh crap. Haven't even noticed that it is written with **dot** ".", thanks. But still it works :)

Comment: @Lincoln - it works, but not exactly the way it should be. It works as if it is `Cells(2)`, and it gives you B1. If it was `Cells(2,1)`, it should have been A2.

Comment: Edited! @Vityata What about copy of the whole sheet range? why it does not work time to time!?

Comment: @Vityata - thanks, that surprises me, learnt something new. Lincoln - I suggest you comment out the On Error line so you can see what's going on.

Comment: Also where do you declare `lrow` and `lcol`?

Comment: @Vityata Do not take it serious, haven't yet rewrite this part.

Comment: When you select the listbox it closes because You tell it to:

Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ListBox1.Value).Activate
    Unload Me
End Sub

The UNLOAD actually closes the form

Comment: @HarassedDad Hi, Yeah I know. The problem is with inputbox it disappears  when macro runs (application.inputbox)

Comment: @Vityata lrow and lcol are declared in Private Sub as per code above. Maybe I am missing something else

Comment: They are therefore only available to that sub. You need to declare outside the procedure if you want them to public.

Comment: @SJR Added. Accidently delete them with comments. Does the merged cells could be the possible reason?

Comment: What if the user wants to cancel the paste while the sheets userform is showing? Also, the do loop after showing the form is not needed as Userformxx.Show already halts the code until the userform is either hidden or unloaded.

Comment: @jkpieterse This is also the issue that I have. I dont now why but without `doevents` loop the code runs behind userform and it copy and paste nothing. That is why I have add this part